# How to apply Nonclustered Index on all tables at once

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have 64 tables in sql server i want to apply nonclustered index in all the tables.Is it possible to apply nonclustered index in all the tables at once using query.Please le me know if there is any way we can apply index using single query

Comment: Wow!, so you are sure all 64 NCI will be used and are created as per query and would benefit SQL Server query processing ? Be cautious when creating indexes unused would slow down inserts

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with cursor and dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  name
    FROM    sys.tables     
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @t

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @s = 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_' + @t + ' ON dbo.' + @t + '(id)'
        EXEC (@s)

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @t
    END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Of course you will need to adjust this to appropriate columns on which you are going to add indexes.